# Sending an email to someone automatically on their birthday

Tags: vba, ms-access

Currently for a project I am trying to make a function that automatically sends an email to a person on their birthday in Microsoft Access using Visual Basic, it is activated with an AutoExec macro. The code I am using is below.

```
Public Function BirthdayEmail()

DoCmd.OpenReport "BirthdayMessageR", acViewNormal, , , acWindowNormal

If Len([Reports]![BirthdayMessageR]![Email Address]) = 0 Then

DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , "test@inet.com", , , "test", "test", True

Else

DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , [Reports]![BirthdayMessageR]![Email Address], , , "test", "test", True

End If

End Function
```

Basically I am trying to make it so when the Email Address value is blank/empty, the email is not sent, but when there is an email, then an email is sent to that address. The only problem is I do not know how to stop the error message appearing when there is no data in the field. The code works perfectly fine when it is someone's birthday, and thus there is a valid email address in the field.

Comment: Should show exact error message and indicate which line triggers. Why even open a report? Birthday message can be included in SendObject message body. Either apply filter to form and cycle form records or open a recordset object and cycle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If field is Null, Len() function will return Null which means Null = 0 will return false because it certainly can't be true and the Else SendObject code will run. Can't compare anything to Null because Null has nothing to compare.

Deal with possibility of Null with Nz() function.

`If Nz([Reports]![BirthdayMessageR]![Email Address], "") = "" Then`

Don't bother sending any email when there is no email address.

```
If Nz([Reports]![BirthdayMessageR]![Email Address], "") <> "" Then
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , [Reports]![BirthdayMessageR]![Email Address], , , "test", "test", True
End If
```

Comment: I see, but this doesn't solve the problem that I cannot put a blank field into the code, I still get the error saying "You entered an expression with no value".

Comment: Error on what line? Suggested code should not error. See revised answer.

Comment: The error appears on the line with the Nz function. I am trying to draw the value from a field on a report, but the report is currently blank, and Access is telling me that I cannot use an expression with no value in it.

Comment: So why is the report blank? If report opens filtered to a  person's record, even if they don't have an email address in field, there should still be other data. Might want to explore report OnNoData event coding.

Comment: The report in question is querying whether anyone's birthday lies on the current date. If someone's birthday lines up with the current date, they appear on the report, however if there is no record where the date of birth is the same as the current date, there are no records to appear on the report.

Comment: Is this checking for only one person or for any and all persons with birthday on current date? Your code would send only one email. What if multiple persons are on report? You need different approach to code. Have code open a recordset and loop recordset to send emails. This is a very common technique and topic of many discussions.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to this if you couldn't already tell haha. So I should open a recordset instead of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: That is my recommendation.

Comment: Alright I'll give that a try, thanks for your help!

Comment: Based on information provided in question (which nowhere mentions that report has no data and therefore is blank, just that a field is empty), suggested answer is appropriate. Take note of Information about dealing with Null for future.